# Correcting imbalances (outterrotated legs)

Tags: muscle-imbalance

Because of imbalances in my hip, my right foot is pointing more out to the side than the left foot is.

I am thinking that if I do squats or kettlebell swings with high symmetry and my feet more parallel than normal it should correct itself over time.

Can this work?
What is likely causing the imbalance - Imbalance in strength?  Tightness?
(My legs have the same length).

Experts I have asked recommend resolving tightness or working on specific weak muscles.

Comment: This sounds like something that you should address with a physical therapist.

Comment: @rrirower - Yes, but it is also an important part of fitness -  To make the body more balanced, or not make it worse.

Comment: @Olav - I agree with rrirower. This could simply be the way your bones are formed, or it could be an imbalance of some kind. The therapist can help determine which, and give you the correct exercises to help. We would just be shooting in the dark. For example, my bones are formed in a way that my right foot points "out" at about 30 degrees. I have to have special spindles on my bike pedals to be long enough to accommodate this.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by imbalances on your hip? I would think it is due to imbalances in your muscles. Do you sit a lot for work?

If your feet is turned outwards (external rotation of your hip and foot), it may indicate tightness in your gluteal muscles and weakness in your hip adductors. You can try performing more exercises for your hip adductors (https://www.healthline.com/health/adductor-exercises) and stretch your gluteal muscles.

Strengthen your overall lower body and pay attention to form when doing exercises.

Comment: my right foot is pointing more out to the side than the left foot (Which must  originate in the hips).  I do sit a lot for work.

Comment: Pointing out more on one side might be due to the muscles that side being tighter and weaker. Sitting a lot can cause your glutes to become weakened and shortened.

Comment: Why would an outwardly turned foot indicate tight glutes and weak adductors? The glutes are internal rotators much more than they are external rotators, and adductors are not internal rotators. Also, how would sitting cause the glutes to shorten when the glutes are stretched (due to requisite hip flexion) during sitting?

Comment: Hey David, my bad in stating glutes will be shortened. In fact, they are lengthened when sitting a lot. 
For this case, I will think that the glutes, specifically the gluteus medius are the primary culprit for his feet pointing outwards, which may indicate knee valgus. Adductors may be relatively tight due to a possibility of compensating for his weak glutes. Glutes are still the main powerhouse for hip extension, lateral stability of the hip, and external rotation of the hip